# How Are Linear Congruential Generator Multipliers Chosen?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, pseudo-random-generator

There are several numbers that keep coming up when looking at certain random number generators, for example 6364136223846793005 is used in newer pcg-family algorithms and seems to draw it from mt19937_64.

How are these numbers chosen? What are their relevance to generation of random values?

Comment: The standard reference on LCG is Donald E. Knuth's [_The Art of Computer Programming_](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html), edition 3, volume 2, section 3.2.1, with summary in section 3.6. But LCGs are very poor RNGs from a cryptographic standpoint; their relevance to this group is as example targets for cryptanalysis.